# Convert raw DB query to Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I've been having some issues with converting this raw query to Laravel query builder:

```
\DB::select("
        select *
        from (
            select *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rownum
            from (
                select * from templates
                where industry_id = 2 and (palette_id = 1 OR palette_id = 2)
            ) as t1
        ) as t2
        WHERE (t2.rownum - 1) % 2 = floor(((t2.rownum - 1) / 2)) % 2
        ORDER BY t2.id"
    );
```

I tried converting it here but got some errors: http://cryptic-peak-77605.herokuapp.com/

Any help is appreciated.